# Media foundation multiple videos playback results in memory-leak & crash after undefined timeframe

Tags: c++, video-streaming, ms-media-foundation

So we are using a stack consisting of c++ media foundation code in order to playback video files. An important requirement is the ability to play these videos in constantly repeating sequences, so every single video slot will periodically change the video it is playing. In our current example we are creating 16 HWNDs to render video into and 16 corresponding player objects. The main application loops over all of them one after another and does the following:

Shutdown the last player
Release the object
CoCreateinstance for a new player
Initialize the player with the (old) HWND
Start Playback
The media player is called "MediaPlayer2", this needs to be built and registered as COM (regsvr32). The main application is to be found in the TAPlayer2 Project. It searches for the CLSID of the player in the registry and instantiates it. As current test file we use a test.mp4 that has to reside on the disk like C:\test.mp4

Now everything goes fine initially. The program loops through the players and the video keeps restarting and playing. The memory footprint is normal and all goes smooth. After a timeframe of anything between 20 minutes and 4 days, all of the sudden things will get weird. At this point it seems as if calls to "InitializeRenderer" by the EVR slow down and eventually don't go through anymore at all. With this, also thread count and memory footprint will start to increase drastically and after a certain amount of time depending on existing RAM all the memory will be exhausted and our application crashes, usually somewhere in the GPU driver or near the EVR DLL.

I am happy to try out any other code examples that propose to solve my issue: displaying multiple video windows at the same time, and looping through them like in a playlist. Needs to be running on Windows 10!
I have been going at this for quite a while now and am pretty hard stuck. I uploaded the above mentioned code example and added the link to this post. This should work out of the box afaik. I can also provide code excerpts in here in the thread if that is preferred.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Thomas

Link to demo project (VS2015): https://filebin.net/l8gl79jrz6fd02vt

edit: the following code from the end of winmain.cpp is used to restart the players:

```
do
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < PLAYER_COUNT; i++)
    {
      hr = g_pPlayer[i]->Shutdown();
      SafeRelease(&g_pPlayer[i]);
      hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AvasysPlayer,  // CLSID of the coclass
        NULL,                         // no aggregation
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,         // the server is in-proc
        __uuidof(IAvasysPlayer),      // IID of the interface we want
        (void**)&g_pPlayer[i]);         // address of our interface pointer

      hr = g_pPlayer[i]->InitPlayer(hwndPlayers[i]);

      hr = g_pPlayer[i]->OpenUrl(L"C:\\test.mp4");
    }

  } while (true);
```

Comment: Try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. Maybe add some snippets of code that produce this error instead of the whole project, this will make it a lot easier to us to help you

Comment: @JohnSmith I'm afraid this is the most minimal, reproducible example I can provide. All individual parts of the code work as expected when tested individually. Only when combined and used together for the actual task (concurrent sequencies/playlists) issue emerge.

Comment: Where is the code where you restart the player ?

Comment: I updated my initial post and added the part that is restarting the players.

Comment: You might have a memory leak inside your player implementation.
I've worked on similar projects (mixing video outputs on the screen) in the past and approached it by using a single DirectX Presenter. I used DirectX 11 VideoProcessBlt to superimpose all video textures (hardware DX 11 decoding) onto the final bigger output DX 11 texture. This was useful both for rendering and recording to a new (mp4/H264) file as well. Each video input was handled b ya separate IMFMediaSource.

Answer (score 2):

Some MediaFoundation interface like

- IMFMediaSource
- IMFMediaSession
- IMFMediaSink

need to be Shutdown before Release them.

> At this point it seems as if calls to "InitializeRenderer" by the EVR slow down and eventually don't go through anymore at all.
>   ... usually somewhere in the GPU driver or near the EVR DLL.

a good track to make a precise search in your code.

In your file PlayerTopoBuilder.cpp, at CPlayerTopoBuilder::AddBranchToPartialTopology :

```
if (bVideo)
{
  if (false) {
    BREAK_ON_FAIL(hr = CreateMediaSinkActivate(pSD, hVideoWnd, &pSinkActivate));
    BREAK_ON_FAIL(hr = AddOutputNode(pTopology, pSinkActivate, 0, &pOutputNode));
  }
    else {
      //// try directly create renderer
      BREAK_ON_FAIL(hr = MFCreateVideoRenderer(__uuidof(IMFMediaSink), (void**)&pMediaSink));
      CComQIPtr<IMFVideoRenderer> pRenderer = pMediaSink;
      BREAK_ON_FAIL(hr = pRenderer->InitializeRenderer(nullptr, nullptr));

      CComQIPtr<IMFGetService> getService(pRenderer);
      BREAK_ON_FAIL(hr = getService->GetService(MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE, __uuidof(IMFVideoDisplayControl), (void**)&pVideoDisplayControl));
      BREAK_ON_FAIL(hr = pVideoDisplayControl->SetVideoWindow(hVideoWnd));

      BREAK_ON_FAIL(hr = pMediaSink->GetStreamSinkByIndex(0, &pStreamSink));
      BREAK_ON_FAIL(hr = AddOutputNode(pTopology, 0, &pOutputNode, pStreamSink));
    }
}
```

You create a IMFMediaSink with MFCreateVideoRenderer and pMediaSink. pMediaSink is release because of the use of CComPtr, but never Shutdown.

You must keep a reference on the Media Sink and Shutdown/Release it when the Player Shutdown.

Or you can use a different approach with MFCreateVideoRendererActivate.

[IMFMediaSink::Shutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-imfmediasink-shutdown)

> If the application creates the media sink, it is responsible for calling Shutdown to avoid memory or resource leaks.
>   In most applications, however, the application creates an activation object for the media sink, and the Media Session uses that object to create the media sink.
>   In that case, the Media Session — not the application — shuts down the media sink. (For more information, see Activation Objects.)

I also suggest you to use this kind of code at the end of CPlayer::CloseSession (after release all others objects) :

```
if(m_pSession != NULL){

    hr = m_pSession->Shutdown();

    ULONG ulMFObjects = m_pSession->Release();
    m_pSession = NULL;

    assert(ulMFObjects == 0);
}
```

For the use of MFCreateVideoRendererActivate, you can look at my MFNodePlayer project :

[MFNodePlayer](https://github.com/mofo7777/MFNode/tree/master/MFNodePlayer)

**EDIT**

I rewrote your program, but i tried to keep your logic and original source code, like CComPtr/Mutex...

[MFMultiVideo](https://github.com/mofo7777/Stackoverflow/tree/master/MFMultiVideo)

Tell me if this program has memory leaks.

It will depend on your answer, but then we can talk about best practices with MediaFoundation.

Another thought :

Your program uses 1 to 16 IMFMediaSession. On a good computer configuration, you could use only one IMFMediasession, i think (Never try to aggregate 16 MFSource).

Visit :

[CustomVideoMixer](https://github.com/mofo7777/Stackoverflow/tree/master/CustomVideoMixer)

to understand the other way to do it.

I think your approach to use 16 IMFMediasession is not the best approach on a modern computer. VuVirt talk about this.

**EDIT2**

I've updated MFMultiVideo using Work Queues.

I think the problem can be that you call MFStartup/MFShutdown for each players.
Just call MFStartup/MFShutdown once in winmain.cpp for example, like my program does.

Comment: In PlayerTopoBuilder.cpp, at CPlayerTopoBuilder::AddBranchToPartialTopology : if you change if(false) to if(true) it should create the Media Sink via MFCreateVideoRendererActivate already, this was my initial implementation but already yielded in a memory leak/crash (after **4 days!**). Does this usage of ActivationObject seem ok to you? Can you suggest closing behaviour for this code? (order of Shutdown/Release)

Comment: Ok, we have to do more than a code review. Before any suggestion, I will do a simple debugging.

Comment: any obervations so far? with the latest changes and using IMFActivate, I am able to see every other minute **one** additional reference on the MediaSession when releasing it and the code leaked memory constantly over a period of 4 days.

Comment: After debugging your code, i don't see memory leaks. The MediaFoundation source code part of your project is correct for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort! I did a bunch of testing with your code and can confirm that your exact implementation does **not** produce memory leaks. It will, however, as soon as I introduce the concept of _MFWorkQueues_ which I absolutely need to get smooth playback on these many videos. 

I feel like I don't know **when** to exactly use _MFUnlockWorkQueue_
I will acquire the work queue during creation of the Source node and so far I am unable to find the right spot during Shutdown. Whereever I put it I will end up with occasional additional references on the MediaSession while releasing.

Comment: I already changed my code to only use MFStartup/MFShutdown once per program run instead of using it every time I create a player. This did improve things a lot, but did not eliminate the leaks completely when using work queues.